# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in flutter how to post json obj like this

Tags: json, list, flutter, api, indexing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ImE7.jpg)

Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in flutter how to post json obj like this

Comment: Take a look: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data.

Answer (score 0):

use `jsonEncode()`

```
final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode({
      'request_detail': [
        {
       }
      ],
      'mobile_number': "0023949234"
    }),
  );
```